# Spring integration use PollableChannel simultaneously

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

In my project, I have the following `List` of `AccountWithFiles` objects.

```
@AllArgsConstructor
  @Getter
  class AccountWithFiles {

    private String account;
    private List<S3FileInfo> s3FileInfoList;
  }
```

I want to process each `AccountWithFiles` separately in a new thread. Then split `s3FileInfoList` using `split()` and process them one by one with 20 min delay, however in parallel each `account` with `s3FileInfoList`.

So I have the following DSL definition:

```
  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow s3DownloadFlowEnhanced() {
    return IntegrationFlows.fromSupplier(s3FileInfoRepository::findAllGroupByAccount,
        c -> c.poller(Pollers.cron(time, TimeZone.getTimeZone(zone))).id("s3TEMPO"))
        .channel("manualS3EnhancedFlow")
        .split()
        .channel("myChannel")
        .get();
  }
```

`s3FileInfoRepository::findAllGroupByAccount` returns the list of `AccountWithFiles` objects after that I'm splitting them and send them to `MessageChannels` `Executors` channel (with defined number of threads)

```
  @Bean
  public MessageChannel myChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.publishSubscribe(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)).get();
  }
```

After that

```
 @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow processEachAccountSeparately() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("myChannel")
        .<AccountWithFiles, Object>transform(m -> m.getS3FileInfoList().stream().sorted(
              Comparator.comparing(i -> i.getOperationType() == FILE_OPERATION_TYPE.ADD))
              .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        .log()
        //.resequence()
        .split()
        .channel("bookItemsChannel")
        .get();
  }
  
  @Bean
  public PollableChannel bookItemsChannel(){
    return new QueueChannel();
  }
  
  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow test() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("bookItemsChannel")
        .delay("delayer.messageGroupId", d -> d
            .defaultDelay(25000L)
            .delayExpression("headers['delay']"))
        .log()
        .get();
  }


  @Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
  public PollerMetadata defaultPoller() {
    PollerMetadata pollerMetadata = new PollerMetadata();
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(5);
    taskExecutor.initialize();

    pollerMetadata.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor);
    pollerMetadata.setTrigger(new PeriodicTrigger(15000L));
    pollerMetadata.setMaxMessagesPerPoll(3);
    return pollerMetadata;
  }
```

When messages are received by the Pollable channel they are processed one by one with delay. I want my messages to process one by one however in parallel based on splitter from `s3DownloadFlowEnhanced`flow.
I know that pollable channels distinguish a sender and receiver for the message in a different thread. Maybe there is any workaround here?

In `processEachAccountSeparately` flow I see that each account has its own thread.

```
    2021-06-24 15:33:34.585  INFO 56174 --- [pool-4-thread-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=[S3FileInfo(fileName=sdfsdf, timeStamp=null, serviceName=null, accountLogin=login2, operationType=ADD)], headers={sequenceNumber=1, correlationId=36b132ac-7c5b-af66-96c0-2334a757c960, id=3bafdaa7-ed4c-087f-5f2c-cc114eae42cd, sequenceSize=2, timestamp=1624538014577}]
    2021-06-24 15:33:34.585  INFO 56174 --- [pool-4-thread-2] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=[S3FileInfo(fileName=sdfjsjfj, timeStamp=null, serviceName=null, accountLogin=login1, operationType=DELETE), S3FileInfo(fileName=s3/outgoing/file2, timeStamp=null, serviceName=IPASS, accountLogin=login1, operationType=DELETE), S3FileInfo(fileName=outgoing/s3/ipass.xlsx, timeStamp=null, serviceName=IPASS, accountLogin=login1, operationType=ADD), S3FileInfo(fileName=dsfsdf, timeStamp=null, serviceName=null, accountLogin=login1, operationType=ADD)], headers={sequenceNumber=2, correlationId=36b132ac-7c5b-af66-96c0-2334a757c960, id=d8506721-2cfd-b6da-d353-4fb8bd5744fb, sequenceSize=2, timestamp=1624538014577}]

However, PollableChannel executes it one by one

2021-06-24 15:33:46.328  INFO 56174 --- [lTaskExecutor-3] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=S3FileInfo(fileName=sdfjsjfj, timeStamp=null, serviceName=null, accountLogin=login1, operationType=DELETE), headers={sequenceNumber=1, sequenceDetails=[[36b132ac-7c5b-af66-96c0-2334a757c960, 2, 2]], correlationId=d8506721-2cfd-b6da-d353-4fb8bd5744fb, id=7f8bd9a6-25ce-0bb2-c3f3-581d823d8fce, sequenceSize=4, timestamp=1624538014585}]
2021-06-24 15:33:46.329  INFO 56174 --- [lTaskExecutor-3] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=S3FileInfo(fileName=sdfsdf, timeStamp=null, serviceName=null, accountLogin=login2, operationType=ADD), headers={sequenceNumber=1, sequenceDetails=[[36b132ac-7c5b-af66-96c0-2334a757c960, 1, 2]], correlationId=3bafdaa7-ed4c-087f-5f2c-cc114eae42cd, id=f697b52b-1053-51aa-232f-88bb602dc1c9, sequenceSize=1, timestamp=1624538014585}]
2021-06-24 15:33:46.329  INFO 56174 --- [lTaskExecutor-3] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=S3FileInfo(fileName=s3/outgoing/file2, timeStamp=null, serviceName=IPASS, accountLogin=login1, operationType=DELETE), headers={sequenceNumber=2, sequenceDetails=[[36b132ac-7c5b-af66-96c0-2334a757c960, 2, 2]], correlationId=d8506721-2cfd-b6da-d353-4fb8bd5744fb, id=a6754c98-fce0-f132-664a-65d61f553ae2, sequenceSize=4, timestamp=1624538014585}]
2021-06-24 15:34:01.333  INFO 56174 --- [lTaskExecutor-4] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=S3FileInfo(fileName=outgoing/s3/ipass.xlsx, timeStamp=null, serviceName=IPASS, accountLogin=login1, operationType=ADD), headers={sequenceNumber=3, sequenceDetails=[[36b132ac-7c5b-af66-96c0-2334a757c960, 2, 2]], correlationId=d8506721-2cfd-b6da-d353-4fb8bd5744fb, id=71fa915a-fcaa-3d00-023b-5cf51be3b183, sequenceSize=4, timestamp=1624538014585}]
2021-06-24 15:34:01.333  INFO 56174 --- [lTaskExecutor-4] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=S3FileInfo(fileName=dsfsdf, timeStamp=null, serviceName=null, accountLogin=login1, operationType=ADD), headers={sequenceNumber=4, sequenceDetails=[[36b132ac-7c5b-af66-96c0-2334a757c960, 2, 2]], correlationId=d8506721-2cfd-b6da-d353-4fb8bd5744fb, id=7c513e23-5484-4f61-b7d3-362648c7b89c, sequenceSize=4, timestamp=1624538014585}]
```

What I want is to have something like this:

```
[pool-4-thread-1] simultaneously 
[pool-4-thread-2] simultaneously
[pool-4-thread-2] 20 min delay
[pool-4-thread-2] 20 min delay
[pool-4-thread-2] 20 min delay
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first step is correct about splitting a list of `AccountWithFiles`. Then you say that you'd like to split `s3FileInfoList` and process them sequentially, one by one, but why you place them into a `QeueuChannel`? The regular, default `DirectChannel` would be enough in this case.

However then you go to `delay()` which does not block the current thread, but schedule a task in a future in a separate thread. So, you probably need to rethink your solution since with the current approach, even if you get rid off that `bookItemsChannel` as a queue, you still are not going to process delayed messages sequentially. There is just no guarantee on `TaskScheduler` which one is going to be performed first when they all have the same schedule time.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Is it possible to make something like this `account1-> S3FileInfo (delay) -> S3FileInfo (delay).  account2-> S3FileInfo (delay) -> S3FileInfo (delay)`.  So account1 and account2 are being processed in parallel but with delay. Frankly saying I've forgot to get rid of `delay()` I've used `Poller` instead.

Comment: It is not possible to achieve exact delay with pollable channel, since your message may appear in a queue in the middle of the current poll cycle. Plus, as you noticed, all the messages are polled by the same thread on the consumer side of the pollable channel. In either case: it is not possible to process in the same thread after delay. You probably may need think about delaying the whole `AccountWithFiles` object and then split its `getS3FileInfoList()` sequentially.